# What is the meaning of the phrase "trading the sensible for the pat"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the following paragraph, what does the highlighted phrase means?

> In Don Giovanni, what is perhaps Mozart’s best-known opera, there exist two distinct endings, a phenomenon not entirely unknown during the composer’s time, but one that invites the obvious question: Why did Mozart decide to include alternate endings for Don Giovanni when he did not do the same with his other famous operas, Die Zauberflöte and Le Nozze di Figaro? Another question, and one not so obvious, is: Why was Mozart himself uncertain as to which of the two endings to choose, as is evidenced in his correspondence with Lorenzo Da Ponte, the opera’s librettist?
> A common answer is to treat both these questions as one: Mozart was uncertain as to which ending to provide, so he wrote both endings. Such a reply ignores an important consideration: Why did Mozart decide to provide these specific endings? Libard provides a reasonable answer: The traditional ending—in the sense that it is the one that was popular during the composer’s day and continues to be so today—is clearly more palatable for audiences. The hero, Don Giovanni, is chided for his libertine ways and then the cast appears in tutti, bellowing a merry chorus as the curtain falls. The audience is left having a light dose of entertainment, which, after all, was the aim of many of the operas of Mozart’s time. Fine, but then what of the tragic ending? Libard—**`trading the sensible for the pat`**—offers little more than that such an ending reflects the political climate of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the whole sentence

> Libard — trading the sensible for the pat — offers little more than that such an ending reflects the political climate of the day.

As Michael Harvey pointed out *pat* means *glib* so the suggestion is that instead of offering what the author believed to be the sensible explanation for the choice of ending Libard replaced it with the glib assertion that it was the political climate of the day which caused Mozart to offer the alternative ending. Offering explanations like "Well that is how it was in those days" does not really explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

"Pat" can be an adjective meaning "already prepared and therefore said without thinking much", or "glib" (with little thought or sincerity).

[Pat (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pat)

Comment: So the person whose name is Libard, is not taking sensible, correct?